# Excel auto completing with the wrong formula when adding new row to table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-2016

I'm trying to make a simple cash flow table, but whenever I add a new row to a formula it add the formula wrong, it even says its wrong and suggests to correct!

The formulas are :

Column D :
[image]

Column E (the problem) :
[image]

And then, when I add a new row, it changed the formula of E for the previous row and makes the new one wrong too :

E2:

[image]

E3:

[image]

If I add a third one, it will even suggest to fix the formula it autocompleted wrong... :

[image]

Just what is going on here? I use subtotal as this is actually an example from a huge table that need to sum based on filters.

There are other questions with the same title here, but they either suggest a VBA answer (not feasible to me) or suggest to redo/reset/try a new worksheet and I've tried all that already.

Comment: It looks like you are adding the rows at the top of the table, which usually seems to confuse Excel.  If that is how you have to work with the table, then at least you only need to correct the formula in one cell and Excel will give you the option to overwrite that correction into all the cells of that column.

Comment: @ReyJuna I actually added at the bottom, it just changed the formula of the one before

Comment: You are right, missed that.  Does look like an Excel bug that happens if you add to the top or bottom, but not in between, so it's not your worksheet at issue.  However, the correct/overwrite is still valid.  I realize that this is prone to issues, such as forgetting to correct before you save/exit, but the only workaround I can think of would be a VBA solution.